# Document Events disabled in macro (Word 2016) after july 2018 update

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365, word-2016

Since an update of Office 365 Business from version 1806 (build 16.0.10228.20134) to 1807 (build 16.0.10325.20082), our word macro code inside document events procedures (Document_Open(), Document_Close(), ...) don't trigger anymore.

Tested with a simple VBA code :

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox "test"
End Sub
```

Before the update, the message box was displayed when opening the document.
After the update, the code is not triggered automatically when opening the document (but the procedure works when executed manually).

Do you know where it comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

This was the result of a recent Office update. It's supposed to have been fixed since.